# is creating a new instance of RowItem for adding a new row in SWT table , won't affect the performance

Tags: eclipse, swt

I am trying to add 1000 of rows in a SWT table. Everytime I am using new RowItem. So I think it is creating a new instance. So this way more number of rows mean more instance . So won't it affect the performance and multi object is getting created and won't it hurt the heap size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are creating TableItems, not RowItems.

You might want to check out [virtual tables](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-SWT-Virtual/Virtual-in-SWT.html) - they allow to instantiate the TableItems on demand, i.e. only when they are needed.